# How to center an image on canvas after rotate the image (Konva.js)

Tags: canvas, android-canvas, konvajs, konva

Here's my code on codesandbox, https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/adoring-shamir-7q32w7?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A79%2C26 
I'm trying to center an image on canvas after rotating the image.

It places image to image's initial top-left x,y position. 
so If the image is rotated, it doesn't come to the center anymore.
If there's any workaround, please share. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```js
function centerImage() {
    const img = imageRef.current;
    if (img) {
      const box = img.getClientRect();
      const offsetX = img.x() - box.x;
      const offsetY = img.y() - box.y;

      img.setAttrs({
        x: CANVAS_SIZE / 2 - box.width / 2 + offsetX,
        y: CANVAS_SIZE / 2 - box.height / 2 + offsetY,
      });
    }
  }
```

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/recursing-margulis-txffh9?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A66%2C3-78%2C4

Comment: I can't see it works. but I have solved this problem in my way!
1. before center image, save the rotation value in state and reset the  image rotation (setAttrs : rotation:0)
2. center image 
   setAttrs({x: (CANVAS_SIZE - width) / 2, y: (CANVAS_SIZE -height) / 2})
3. and rotation with save rotation value.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem!

1. before center image, save the rotation value in state and reset the image rotation.
2. center image
3. and rotation again with saved rotation value.

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/vigorous-proskuriakova-pgm2ms?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A103%2C20